# Managed (.NET) Subversion Server

Tags: .net, svn

I'm perfectly aware that there are lots of *client* libraries to connect to an SVN repo, manage working copies, etc. What I'm looking for, though, is an implementation of Subversion *server* for .NET (or a wrapper around some low-level code).

Are there any or I'm asking for something unreasonable (well, sure I do, since I understand how much effort would it take to build an SVN server basically from scratch).

Comment: The question is: Why would you wanna do that?

Comment: Full C# client implementation at [SharpCsvLib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpcvslib/)

Comment: @ParmesanCodice: This is a *CVS*-*Client* Library.

Comment: @Bobby, that's why I put it in the comments, and not as an answer. It's the only 100% C# library I know of that is *similar* to what Anton wants...

Answer (score -1):

[VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com) Server if a free subversion server for Windows ... not sure if this is quite what you are after though.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: This is just a wrapper around Apache HTTP Server